# Is there a shortcut to the MARK / FIXME / TODO menu?

Tags: xcode

Somebody knows the shortcut to this menu (MARK, TODO, FIXME) from the jumpbar ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is one, <kbd>⌃6</kbd> (control-6)